# Node js - MS SQL, не могу достучаться до бд

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Пытаюсь на node js подключиться к ms sql и забрать данные из таблицы.
Запрос выглядит так:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')
const config = {
    server: "LEGION",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
}

sql.connect(config, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.query("SELECT * FROM sys.databases", (err, records) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(records)
        }
    })
})
```

Данные, которые я получаю на скрине ниже, заскринил не все, но суть в том, что я получаю данные из 4 баз данных в папке system databases: master, model, msdb и tempdb. В данном случае это выглядит логично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

MS SQL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я пытаюсь сделать запрос для получения данных из бд School:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')
const config = {
    server: "LEGION",
    database: "School",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
}

sql.connect(config, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Students", (err, records) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(records)
        }
    })
})
```

То получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался подключаться и через Windows Auth, и через SQL Server Auth, ни там, ни там не получается достичь цели.
Для подключения пытался использовать модули mssql, msnodesqlv8, tedious, sequelize по статьям, видео, урокам разных годов, начиная с 2008, насколько я понял, современный вариант делается через tedious и sequelize, а msnodesqlv8 и mssql устарел.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Все работает как нужно, помогла переустановка SQL Server